# How does a Monero pool confirm/reject a submitted nonce?

Tags: mining-pools, mining-theory, protocol, hash-verification

I'm trying to get a handle on how the protocol works between Monero miners and pools.  Although I've looked at Stratum, the rules seem slightly different with Monero mining.  For example, I'm using a CryptoNoter tool (derived from Coinhive) and when it subits a share to the pool the request looks like the below

```
{"type":"submit", "params":{"job_id":"966964311173375", "nonce":"9be9fff4", "result":"40ff373cd53535952c5b195f5fafeaeb632ed5742fc6ad426d083f4bd7290200"}
```

I got the following response from the pool with reference to what I sent ...

```
{"type":"hash_accepted","params":{"hashes":1}
```

What exactly does the above mean?  I see "hash_accepted" so I'm thinking it means teh pool accepted my submission?  If so, what does "hashes" mean?  If not, what does the above response mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hash_accepted field is the response from the proxy server for when a hash is acknowledged by the server the hashes field is the number of hashes the worker has submitted in the past.

When the server gets a new connection it sets it up like so:

```
var conn = {
    uid: null,
    pid: crypto.randomBytes(12).toString("hex"),
    workerId: null,
    found: 0,
    accepted: 0,
    ws: ws,
    pl: new net.Socket(),
}
```

This creates a variable called accepted and set to 0. now when a valid share is called this snippet of code is called which increments the accepted hashes and responds to the client:

```
conn.accepted++;
buf = {
    "type": "hash_accepted",
    "params": {
        "hashes": conn.accepted
     }
}
```

These code snippets are pulled from the server.js file on the CryptoNoter Github page, found [here](https://github.com/cryptonoter/CryptoNoter/blob/master/server.js)